# interlinking point to old domain after migration

Tags: wordpress

I migrated site A to site B, but in site B my interlinking still point to site A. Is there any way to change all of those link? It's difficult to change it manually because there are thousand of them.

Btw, I use 301 redirect. Should I change the url or just leave it there? My concern is SEO.

Comment: You might just want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your URL's and redirecting them is very important. I think you should definitely read this article. 
https://savvypanda.com/blog/intermediate-level/how-to-change-domain-names-not-lose-seo.html

It has everything you need to know about changing your domain name without loosing SEO value.